# Tomcat 8 giving JSP compilation error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-luna, tomcat8

I was using tomcat 7 and just upgraded to tomcat 8. But when I run my web application on tomcat server. It gives this error.

```
Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [42] in the generated java file: [/home/jamil/LunaWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/work/Catalina/localhost/svc/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
The method getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest

    Stacktrace:
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:199)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**My Pom.xml File:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>svc</groupId>
    <artifactId>svc</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>svc Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ptgoetz</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-signals</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1-incubating</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.98.4-hadoop2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
            <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.32</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.1</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>svc</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Whats the reason for this error and what can be the possible solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`getDispatcherType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getDispatcherType()) is only available in Servlet spec 3.0 and greater. [compojure](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.storm/storm-core)  has a dependency hierarchy that looks like

```
storm-core 0.9.1
   compojure 1.1.3
     ring-core 1.1.5
      servlet-api 2.5
```

Even the latest version of the jar has dependency on the old servlet jar file so you need to find a replacement, exclude the offending dependencies within the `compojure` dependency tag itself  or remove the dependency completely.

Comment: I am having servlet 3.0 in pom.xml and web.xml is also adjusted for 3.0

Comment: I would say to check the classpath of your web container to see if you are using an old pre-3.0 jar

Comment: How can I check that please?

Comment: The problem is probably with your deployed app so the first place to look is in the `WEB-INF/lib` location

Comment: What should i look for in WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: Can you post your pom file? It will save any guesswork

Comment: Posted in original question

Comment: It's possible that another dependency in your pom file has an old version of `ServletRequest`. An easy way to find all versions of the file is to use Eclipse and use Open Type (CTRL+Shift+T). Check the method exists for each the classes under Maven Dependencies

Comment: When i typed ServletRequest in open type then i can see servlet 2.5 api as well in my repository. Is that creating problem>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64070/discussion-between-reimeus-and-mr37037).