# dspace 5.0 jspui page not displaying after successful installation on Centos 7

Tags: dspace

I upgraded to DSpace 5.0 from 4.2. I installed DSpace 5.0 freshly. That is, I created a new database and a new installation folder before building and deploying. In the [dspace-source]/build.properties, I specified jspui as my user interface. After installation I'm unable to access jspui from the browser, whereas the xmlui is working perfectly. The jspui comes up as a blank page.

Could someone help me out. Thanks in advance

[Here](http://pastebin.com/7x2dtk2T) is my dspace error log.

Comment: Try looking for errors in your dspace.log, it would help you figure out what's wrong why jspui comes up as a blank page.

Comment: @euler I've added a link to the error log. the error says `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:`. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, when I encountered that error, I replaced all instances of `<artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>` with `<artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>` to all the pom.xml files as stated here: [install error for upstream/master](http://dspace.2283337.n4.nabble.com/install-error-for-upstream-master-tp4676859p4676869.html) and [here](http://dspace.2283337.n4.nabble.com/install-error-for-upstream-master-tp4676859p4676872.html)

Also try to delete or remove the

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

from dspace-api.pom.xml and do an mvn clean after changing the pom.xml files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did the same, had to change a bunch of pom.xml files. I also changed my servlet-api version to 3.1.0. Did an mvn clean package and ant update, and voila! I got my jspui interface. This was such a tedious solution. Is there no better way? Will moving to a lower version of tomcat help?

Comment: @PoonamAnthony, yes it was such a tedious solution if you're not using an IDE. If you're using an IDE like Intellij, it would make your coding easier. I did not encounter that error in our production server which is using tomcat 7, but sooner or later, we would have to upgrade to tomcat 8 if it is really required.

Comment: Thanks, I'll import my dspace code into an IDE. This problem had me scratching my head for the last 3 days, until I finally found a solution to it today.

Comment: Thanks @euler, I thought I'd seen this before somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

According to your log file, you're using Tomcat 8. Other people are reporting similar problems with Tomcat 8 (not with DSpace though): [getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436463/getdispatchertype-is-undefined-for-the-type-httpservletrequest) and [Tomcat 8 giving JSP compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682862/tomcat-8-giving-jsp-compilation-error)

DSpace 5 is supposed to work with Tomcat 8 -- the installation instructions say "Tomcat 7 or later": https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Installing+DSpace#InstallingDSpace-ServletEngine(ApacheTomcat7orlater,Jetty,CauchoResinorequivalent)

You say you were using Tomcat 8 with DSpace 4.2 already, so this probably isn't it. Can you confirm that you ran maven with the "clean" target?

`mvn clean package`

Comment: yes I was using Tomcat 8.0.17 with dspace 4.2. I came across the same problem being reported [Here](http://sourceforge.net/p/dspace/mailman/message/33532346/). But the solution is not very clear to me.

Comment: I just saw that you said you created a new installation folder, so the mvn clean may not do too much. This is starting to sound like a DSpace bug, so you may wish to report this on the official DSpace bug tracker: https://jira.duraspace.org/browse/DS/